# How to migrate relational database in symfony 4?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony4

I have created the table "Category" and added fields 
After that I have add table "Product" as relational database with table "category"
While migrating it throws error

An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE category (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, category VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'category' already exists
[Error whiledoing migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O7ZK.png)

[Refered Link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html)

Comment: The migration is supposed to spot the differences between the database and your model classes and it is the migration that should create the new tables or new columns in existing tables.

Comment: Please write your error as text to the question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes @RiggsFolly. But New table is not created it throws  (Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'category' already exists) Give me some clue to overcome this

Comment: Have you tried to remove your tables already created and doing a new migration?

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly and Nathan Meyer for your suggestions.

Comment: When i try to change the column as relational database it throws error as 

Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Give me some clues to get out of this